# How to change the path to the folder of the XML syntax files? (gedit)

Tags: directory, gedit, syntax-highlighting

Any clue about the variable to be changed in order for gedit to read XML files in another folder?

Currently syntax files are in:

```
/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs
```

I'd like gedit to read XML somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [developer documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-reference.html), You can add custom language definitions under the `$XDG_DATA_HOME/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs` directory (or replace 2.0 with 3.0, for gtksourceview-3.0). The `$XDG_DATA_HOME` variable defaults to `$HOME/.local/share/`.

It should also read these files from a `gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/` sub-directory underneath any path specified in the `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` path environment variable.